# From PHP workers to Python threads

Tags: php, python, multithreading

Right now I'm running 50 PHP (in CLI mode) individual workers (processes) per machine that are waiting to receive their workload (job). For example, the job of resizing an image. In workload they receive the image (binary data) and the desired size. The worker does it's work and returns the resized image back. Then it waits for more jobs (it loops in a smart way). I'm presuming that I have the same executable, libraries and classes loaded and instantiated 50 times. Am I correct? Because this does not sound very effective.

What I'd like to have now is one process that handles all this work and being able to use all available CPU cores while having everything loaded only once (to be more efficient). I presume a new thread would be started for each job and after it finishes, the thread would stop. More jobs would be accepted if there are less than 50 threads doing the work. If all 50 threads are busy, no additional jobs are accepted.

I am using a lot of libraries (for Memcached, Redis, MogileFS, ...) to have access to all the various components that the system uses and Python is pretty much the only language apart from PHP that has support for all of them.

Can Python do what I want and will it be faster and more efficient that the current PHP solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most probably - yes. But don't assume you have to do multithreading. Have a look at the multiprocessing module. It already has an implementation of a Pool included, which is what you could use. And it basically solves the GIL problem (multithreading can run only 1 "standard python code" at any time - that's a very simplified explanation).

It will still fork a process per job, but in a different way than starting it all over again. All the initialisations done- and libraries loaded before entering the worker process will be inherited in a copy-on-write way. You won't do more initialisations than necessary and you will not waste memory for the same libarary/class if you didn't actually make it different from the pre-pool state.

So yes - looking only at this part, python will be wasting less resources and will use a "nicer" worker-pool model. Whether it will really be faster / less CPU-abusing, is hard to tell without testing, or at least looking at the code. Try it yourself.

Added: If you're worried about memory usage, python may also help you a bit, since it has a "proper" garbage collector, while in php GC is a not a priority and not that good (and for a good reason too).

Answer (score 4):

Linux has shared libraries, so those 50 php processes use mostly the same libraries. 
You don't sound like you even have a problem at all.

*"this does not sound very effective."* is not a problem description, if anything those words are a problem on their own. Writing code needs a *real reason*, else you're just wasting time and/or money.

Python is a fine language and won't perform worse than php. Python's [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module will probably help a lot too. But there isn't much to gain if the php implementation is not completly insane. So why even bother spending time on it when everything works? That is usually the goal, not a reason to rewrite ...

Comment: While this is true, it will be true only for the code part. Let's say that the needed library allocates X bytes of private data of which 50% never changes during execution. 50 php processes will share the code + allocate 50*X. Python library will allocate X and after forking will use only (X/2 + 50*X/2), because it will also share unchanged data. The percentage depends on the library of course. X might be so close to 0, that it might not make a difference, but otoh it might be quite high...

Answer (score 1):

If you are on a sane operating system then shared libraries should only be loaded once and shared among all processes using them.  Memory for data structures and connection handles will obviously be duplicated, but the overhead of stopping and starting the systems may be greater than keeping things up while idle.  If you are using something like gearman it might make sense to let several workers stay up even if idle and then have a persistent monitoring process that will start new workers if all the current workers are busy up until a threshold such as the number of available CPUs.  That process could then kill workers in a LIFO manner after they have been idle for some period of time.